# Can someone explain this template function declaration syntax

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers

I do not understand the following template declaration in the boost::python library (line 47 of .../boost_1_51/boost/python/detail/msvc_typeinfo.hpp  to be precise):

```
template< typename T > T&(* is_ref_tester1(type<T>) )(type<T>) { return 0; }
```

where `type` is `template <class T> struct type {};`

It seems to be functionally equivalent to:

```
template<typename T>
struct func_type_getter {
    typedef T&(*func_type)(type<T>);
};


template< typename T >
typename func_type_getter<T>::func_type is_ref_tester1(type<T>) { return 0; }
```

Are these equivalent, is it just a shorthand, or can someone explain the differences?

Comment: Yes, it's an awkward "shorthand" for a function returning a function pointer.

Comment: Interestingly, http://cdecl.org chokes on it (once you remove the templates, which it doesn’t support). It works after replacing `T` with `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the two are equivalent. Here is, how the one-liner is read:

```
template< typename T > T&(* is_ref_tester1(type<T>) )(type<T>) { return 0; }
                       ^           ^        ^            ^
                       |           |        |            |
                       |           |        |     3. it's return type is a pointer to a function taking a type<T>
                       |           |        |
                       |           |    2. it's a function taking a type<T>
                       |           |
                       |   1. this is the declared identifier
                       |
         4. this is the return type of the function whose pointer is returned
```

Comment: Just for interest, why can't I write (removing the template stuff for clarity) `int&(*)(type<int>) is_ref_tester1(type<int>){ return 0; }`?